# NVIDIA 970 running in software rendering mode

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia

I am trying to get a GEforce 970 running on linux mint, and I am stuck in software rendering mode after doing the following:

1. adding the ppa from [here](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)
2. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340`
3. reboot (after update)- no gui
4. remove graphics card and edit grub default to include `nomodeset`
5. reinsert graphica card
6. now running in software rendering mode
7. tried `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` with no change.

Anybody have any ideas? I cant seem to find anything on the help forums I checked that works.

Comment: Please let me know why you downvoted this question so I can improve it

Comment: Have a look at the [arch minimal xorg config for nvidia](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Minimal_configuration) apart from that you're likely to need `Option "AccelMethod" "<something>"`.  I have a Radeon in which I use `glamor` but I do not really know the NVIDIA options for AccelMethod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a GTX 970, you should either use `nouveau` (the open source Nvidia driver), or the plain old proprietary `nvidia` module. Both tend to be pretty iffy (why I'm switching to Radeon graphics), so I would recommend finding which one works best for you.

As for getting out of software rendering mode, have you tried removing `nomodeset` from grub default and doing `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` when `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is your grub config file? Also make sure that you remove `nvidia-340` and `sudo modprobe nvidia` when you have only that installed.